# How much vinegar should I use to flush a 75 Gal hot water tank?

Tags: plumbing

I have a lot of sediment in my 75 gallon hot water tank. My hot water cut out 3 times this year because of it.

I want to flush the tank with [20% vinegar](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07DQTYJ6F). The procedure seems pretty straightforward, but I can't figure out how much vinegar I should use. Online sources say anywhere from 1 to 4 gallons, which is a pretty massive range. Once I fill the tank with it, I'll be leaving it to soak overnight.

What's a good amount to use?

Update: As requested, [some photos](https://photos.app.goo.gl/EKZeoxafwHvbsZTg9)

Comment: The descaling procedure for a tankless WH that I use prescribes regular distilled white vinegar, 5 % acetic acid.  Is this use of 20 % vinegar a widely accepted procedure?

Comment: I was at one time in charge of maintenance of the piped-to-each-bench distilled water system of a testing laboratory. A coworker and I disassembled our 35-year-old steam heated still to descale the boiler. The scale was hard and adhering to the bottom of the boiler, which was tin coated copper. We tried acetic acid in various strengths with no success.  At our recommendation management ordered an entire new still, constructed entirely of titanium alloy. I have to wonder if it is worth it to try to descale a natural gas fired tank made of glass lined steel.

Comment: @JimStewart No idea. I'm not a plumber. First time I'm flushing a tank. I just figured I wouldn't need as much of it, and 20% vinegar isn't hard to find in large quantities on Amazon. If jwh20 recommends 4 gallons of regular vinegar, and 20% is 4 times the concentration of acid, it sounds like a single 1 gallon (4 litre) jug like the one I linked to should do the trick

Comment: @JimStewart for the record, my tank is electric. With so much sediment floating around the tank, it sticks to the heating elements, and either shorts them out, or coats them, making them ineffective. I'm hoping flushing with vinegar, and replacing the anode rod helps

Comment: How often do you have to replace the heating elements? You might be better off draining and flushing the tank to get rid of suspended scale and then replacing the heating elements at 5 year service as opposed to using vinegar to try to dissolve adhering scale. Do electric tanks fail catastrophically like gas fired tanks? What does vinegar do to the heating element?

Comment: Is this a steel tank or a polymer tank? How long has it been in service?

Comment: Take care of that water tank. You will never be able to buy another *immersion heater* anywhere near that large.  All larger water heaters must now be gas or heat-pump tech.

Comment: I am nearly 80 years old. In my youth I ruined some things by over-aggressive and uninformed attempts to maintain them at full function. For some equipment it is better that it be allowed to slowly degrade and then at some point be replaced. The OP should  check on the risks of acid cleaning his electric tank WH.

Comment: The condo is 5 years old, so that's about the age of the tank. [This is the tank](https://www.hotwater.com/support/ECT-80/). Like I said, I lost hot water 3 times now this year, so this isn't maintenance for the sake of maintenance - it's definitely having issues, and they are all related to the sediment that's in there. Cold showers aren't fun.

Comment: What was the repair that restored it to functioning? The specs say that this WH has a 6 year warranty extendible to 10. Acid cleaning might void the warranty. This may be a low end builder's model.

Comment: @JimStewart The plumbers that came the first time had to replace the heating elements because they were covered in minerals. After a few months, when it failed again, I took them out myself, and one of them was shorted out by the minerals. I cleaned it, scraping the minerals off, and it worked fine. The third time, a few months later, they were covered in minerals again.

Comment: Sounds like you need a water softener. I wonder if that could be put in the cold water line feeding the hot water tank or whether it makes sense to soften all the water used inside. In some houses the incoming water line divides, before entering the house, into inside and outside. In houses where it doesn't divide it might make sense to soften only the water going into the water heater. Do you have a problem with mineral deposits in shower heads? – Jim

Comment: @JimStewart There's a bit of buildup on the shower head - not enough to be a problem yet. Water softeners are expensive, especially since my pipes are copper, which apparently takes some sort of specialist to weld.

Comment: Usually nowadays the two connections to the water heater are bendable and are a threaded connection where they connect to the tank. If yours is that way, then probably the company that would install and maintain the water softener could separate the connections and reconnect with just wrenches. Could you take a picture of the top of the tank showing the connections and insert this into your question? You use the edit link at the bottom left.

Comment: Do you have any reason to think the debris is carbonate ( affected by acid) ? The debris in my heater is not carbonate.

Comment: @blacksmith37 All I know is water heaters are cleaned with Vinegar. If there was a different way to clean them, I might try that too if vinegar doesn't work. I can probably just take out my heating element, which is covered in the debris, and see if the vinegar will dissolve it before I pump the entire water heater full of vinegar.

Answer (score 0):

I did this recently with a 50 gal hot water heater and I used 4 gal. of vinegar.  So I'd use at least that much with your 75 gal. tank.

In addition to letting it be there overnight, I also used a small pump to circulate the liquid using the drain as the inlet to the pump and putting the vinegar back into via the tank's normal inlet pipe.  While I can't prove it, I believe the circulation let to more complete dissolving of the deposits.

Comment: Was this a gas fired tank?

Comment: Electric, in this case

Comment: AFIK It is the gas fired tanks that fail catastrophically due to scaling. In those the flame is outside the tank and heats the water by conduction through the bottom wall of the tank. Scale forms and adheres to the water side opposite the burner. This prevents water from contact with the bottom and so the glass lined steel is overheated and fails. Electric tank heaters have the element immersed in the water and so the wall of the tank is not degraded.